# Drupal.behaviors Once() won't execute

Tags: theming, 8, javascript, blocks

I have created a custom block that shows some parking information for the user (using json) and this worked fine for most pages, but when I visit any created nodes (pages like /node/1,/node/2) the jquery get executed twice (so the information is added twice to the parkings-div in the block). After some searching, I thought using "once" would solve my problem but after adding this it doesn't execute at all.

```
(function ($) {
    "use strict";

Drupal.behaviors.Parkings = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
        $('#parkings',context).once('parkingsbehavior', function () {
            getAndShowResults();
        });

        function getAndShowResults() {
            var root_url = getRootUrl();
            $.get(root_url + "parkings", {})
                    .done(function (data) {
                        var i;
                        for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                            var p = $(document.createElement("p"));
                            var p_text = data[i].description + ', free: ' + data[i].parkingStatus.availableCapacity;
                            p.append(p_text);
                            p.appendTo("#parkings");
                        }
                    });
        }

        function getRootUrl() {
            return window.location.origin ? window.location.origin + '/' : window.location.protocol + '/' + window.location.host + '/';
        }
}};

}(jQuery));
```

This is my routing file:

```
parkings.content:
      path: '/parkings'
      defaults:
        _controller: '\Drupal\parkings\Controller\ParkingsController::content'
        _title: 'Parkings Gent'
      requirements:
       _permission: 'access content'
```

and I've added these dependencies:

```
    - core/jquery
    - core/drupal.ajax
    - core/drupal
    - core/drupalSettings
    - core/jquery.once
```

Am I misunderstanding how once() works or am I just using it wrong?

(I'm using Drupal 8 v1.8)

Comment: Once has changed with jQuery 2.x, see the Drupal changelog for info. I ran into the same issue and that fixed it for me: https://www.drupal.org/node/2457769 - Essentially now you are going to want to do `once('mybehavior').each(function()`

Comment: ok I will add it as an answer

Answer (score 12, accepted):

jQuery Once has changed with jQuery 2.x, see the Drupal [changelog](http://drupal.org/node/2457769) for info.

I ran into the same issue and that fixed it for me:

Essentially now you are going to want to do:

`...once('mybehavior').each(function()...`